# vertical-align: top not working on Opera

Tags: html, css

I have 2  div must be placed in-line. here is my css

```
.div1,#div2{
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 width:200px
}

.div1{
 width:200px;
 float:left
}

#div2{
 width:200px;
 float:right
}
```

Here is HTML

```
<a href="#" class='div1'>Home</a>
<a href="#" class='div1'>About</a>
<a href="#" class='div1'>Contact</a>
<a href="#" class='div1'>Location</a>
<div id='div2'>User</div>
```

the problem is all .div1 are arrange in in-line and vertically top. But #div2 not in the same row (in-line but not vertically top). This ok with Firefox, but opera doesn't. What is the wrong in css? What  should I do?

Comment: I don't know what version of FF you're using but the FF 28 (latest version) renders it the same as Opera does.

Comment: Opera 12.16 . FF 28.0

Comment: I solved this problem. Thanks everyone who contribute their attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to mix floats and display: inline-block.

This would achieve the same thing with display:inlne-block
http://fiddle.jshell.net/czWDM/2/
http://fiddle.jshell.net/czWDM/2/show/

```
.div1, #div2 {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 200px;
}

#div2{
 text-align: right;
}
```

This would achieve the same thing with floats (though difference is that you would not have vertical alignement and the possible additinal white-space caused by IB elements:
http://jsfiddle.net/KhN3L/1/
http://jsfiddle.net/KhN3L/1/show/

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

.div1, #div2 {
 float: left;
 display: block;
 width: 200px;
}
#div2{
 float: right;
}
```